# Ввод даты в EditText

Tags: java, android, дата

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date" />
```

Когда вводишь цифры, по идее через определенное количество символов должно ставиться ТИРЕ. Но у меня все цифры иду без никаких знаков. Точнее мне нужна точка типа как 12.12.2001.

Вопрос: Как подставлять символ, мне кажется я не вижу очевидное?

Comment: Есть более удобные способы ввода даты, например DatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует использовать [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) для такой задачи, написать кастомный наследник. Пример можете взглянуть например [тут](http://suvitruf.ru/2012/09/19/1974/)